# Command for opening application using java through terminal?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, java, startup, executable

I downloaded Tomighty(pomodoro app) on my Ubuntu 12.04. Everytime i have to start tomighty, i have to right click on the tomighty's jar file and click on open with sun java 7.

is there any command which i can save and just double clicking on it or adding it at startup execute it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can run jar files using this command:

```
java -jar NameOfJar.jar
```

Comment: To make a clickable desktop entry, I'd recommend to use the menu editor named alacarte. With that you can easily put any command in Ubuntus menus, and from there you can simply drag and drop it to your desktop, if you like. When creating a menu entry, you might need to specify the full path to the jar file and maybe enclose it in quotation marks.

Answer (score 2):

Right click the `.jar` file, click on **Properties**. In the **Open With** tab you can choose the default application. Choose Sun Java 7.

Now you should be able to just double click it.

[image: Properties - Open With]